# Firebase remote authentication

Tags: php, firebase-authentication

I have a question. I record the requests coming with the api to the realtime database with firebase php. But I don't know how to authenticate. When a user makes a request to the api, how do I verify that person in firebase?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the user making the request is signed in with Firebase Authentication, you can pass their ID token with the request and then verify that ID token in your PHP code.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). If you're using the `kreait/firebase-php` package, that also has a section on [verifying a Firebase ID Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) in its docs.